# ARRAY LIST VIEW

Tags: android, android-studio, json, arraylist

Quiero crear un list view donde se vea algo asi:

[image: list view]

Y no se como hacer para que sea un arraylist, hice esto pero no quedo como queria:

[image: LIST VIEW ERROR]

Esos montos los obtengo de un json, sin embargo las descripciones no.

Codigo donde creo el ARRAYLIST y obtengo de un request el JSON e indico el ADAPTER:

```
try {
            rescompra = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("RESUMEN_COMPRA"));
            JSONArray jsonArray = rescompra.getJSONArray("payment_methods");
            JSONObject totals = rescompra.getJSONObject("totals");
            cantItem = totals.getString("items_qty");
            subTotal = totals.getString("subtotal");
            subTotalDesc = totals.getString("subtotal_with_discount");
            descuento = totals.getString("discount_amount");
            envio = totals.getString("shipping_amount");
            envioDesc = totals.getString("shipping_discount_amount");
            impuesto = totals.getString("tax_amount");
            impuestoEnvio = totals.getString("shipping_tax_amount");
            moneda = totals.getString("quote_currency_code");
            grandTotal = totals.getString("grand_total");

                ArrayList<String> ListaResumen = new ArrayList<String>();
                ListaResumen.add(cantItem + " " + moneda);
                ListaResumen.add(subTotal + " " + moneda);
                ListaResumen.add(subTotalDesc + " " + moneda);
                ListaResumen.add(descuento + " " + moneda);
                ListaResumen.add(envio + " " + moneda);
                ListaResumen.add(envioDesc + " " + moneda);
                ListaResumen.add(impuesto + " " + moneda);
                ListaResumen.add(impuestoEnvio + " " + moneda);
                ListaResumen.add(grandTotal + " " + moneda);

                ListaResumen.add("SubTotal:");
                ListaResumen.add("SubTotal con Descuento:");
                ListaResumen.add("Descuento:");
                ListaResumen.add("Envio:");
                ListaResumen.add("Envio con Descuento:");
                ListaResumen.add("Impuesto:");
                ListaResumen.add("Impuesto de Envio:");
                ListaResumen.add("Total:");


        List<String> resumenComprasList = new ArrayList<>();
        resumenComprasList = ListaResumen;
        ResumenComprasAdapter adapter = new ResumenComprasAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.compras_resumen_listview,resumenComprasList);
        lvResumenCompras.setAdapter(adapter);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

CODIGO DEL ADAPTER:

```
public class ResumenComprasAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private List<String> resumenComprasList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ResumenComprasAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        resumenComprasList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.compras_resumen_listview, null);
        }

        final TextView   valor, descripcion;
          valor = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.valor);
          descripcion = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc_view);

          valor.setText(resumenComprasList.get(position));;
          descripcion.setText(resumenComprasList.get(position));

          return convertView;

    }
```

Este es JSON que recibo en RESCOMPRA:

```
{"payment_methods":[{"code":"checkmo","title":"Check \/ Money order"},{"code":"banktransfer","title":"Braintree"}],"totals":{"grand_total":97,"base_grand_total":97,"subtotal":87,"base_subtotal":87,"discount_amount":0,"base_discount_amount":0,"subtotal_with_discount":87,"base_subtotal_with_discount":87,"shipping_amount":10,"base_shipping_amount":10,"shipping_discount_amount":0,"base_shipping_discount_amount":0,"tax_amount":0,"base_tax_amount":0,"weee_tax_applied_amount":null,"shipping_tax_amount":0,"base_shipping_tax_amount":0,"subtotal_incl_tax":87,"shipping_incl_tax":10,"base_shipping_incl_tax":10,"base_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","items_qty":2,"items":[{"item_id":312,"price":18,"base_price":18,"qty":1,"row_total":18,"base_row_total":18,"row_total_with_discount":0,"tax_amount":0,"base_tax_amount":0,"tax_percent":0,"discount_amount":0,"base_discount_amount":0,"discount_percent":0,"price_incl_tax":18,"base_price_incl_tax":18,"row_total_incl_tax":18,"base_row_total_incl_tax":18,"options":"[{\"value\":\"Advanced Pilates & Yoga (Strength)\",\"label\":\"Downloads\"}]","weee_tax_applied_amount":null,"weee_tax_applied":null,"name":"Advanced Pilates & Yoga (Strength)"},{"item_id":313,"price":69,"base_price":69,"qty":1,"row_total":69,"base_row_total":69,"row_total_with_discount":0,"tax_amount":0,"base_tax_amount":0,"tax_percent":0,"discount_amount":0,"base_discount_amount":0,"discount_percent":0,"price_incl_tax":69,"base_price_incl_tax":69,"row_total_incl_tax":69,"base_row_total_incl_tax":69,"options":"[]","weee_tax_applied_amount":null,"weee_tax_applied":null,"name":"Abominable Hoodie-XL-Red"}],"total_segments":[{"code":"subtotal","title":"Subtotal","value":87},{"code":"shipping","title":"Shipping & Handling (Best Way - Table Rate)","value":10},{"code":"tax","title":"Tax","value":0,"extension_attributes":{"tax_grandtotal_details":[]}},{"code":"grand_total","title":"Grand Total","value":97,"area":"footer"}]}}
```

Comment: Hola @Valentina, tu código no esta mal para nada, solo que en la parte del diseño podrías mejorar algunas cosas para tener un código fuente más limpio y depurado. Que tal si agregas a tu pregunta un json de ejemplo para poder ayudarte de una mejor manera.

Comment: Hola, este es el json que recibo de totals:

Comment: "totals":{"grand_total":97,"base_grand_total":97,"subtotal":87,"base_subtotal":87,"discount_amount":0,"base_discount_amount":0,"subtotal_with_discount":87,"base_subtotal_with_discount":87,"shipping_amount":10,"base_shipping_amount":10,"shipping_discount_amount":0,"base_shipping_discount_amount":0,"tax_amount":0,"base_tax_amount":0,"weee_tax_applied_amount":null,"shipping_tax_amount":0,"base_shipping_tax_amount":0,"subtotal_incl_tax":87,"shipping_incl_tax":10,"base_shipping_incl_tax":10,"base_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","items_qty":2

Comment: edita la pregunta y deja el json en la pregunta porque el comentario tiene un limite de caracteres

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Gracias @Valentina, te ayudaré por pasos. Enfocate en la clase adapter, en el método constructor la lista que alimenta el adapter es de tipo `String`. Pero necesitas una lista que guarde la descripción y el valor de esa descripción. Paso 1. Necesitas crear una clase con las propiedades descripcion y valor. Paso 2. Cambia el tipo del `ArrayList<String>ListaResumen` a `ArrayList<ClaseNueva>ListaResumen`. Para llenarlo es lo mismo `ListaResumen.add(new ClaseNueva("Subtotal:", cantItem + " " + moneda));` Cambia el constructor del adapter para que reciba el nuevo ArrayList<ClaveNueva>

Comment: Soy nueva creando esos adapter, disculpa mi ignorancia... Me podrias explicar algo mas especifico, hay cosas que aun no manejo muy bien

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90332/discussion-between-gustavo-mora-and-valentina).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar varias opciones, yo te propongo usar un `LinkedHashMap` para almacenar los valores, por ejemplo:

almacenar el key `"SubTotal:"` y el value `subTotal + " " + moneda`

además el uso del LinkedHashMap  asegura el orden en los elementos, define el LinkedHashMap y agrega los valores de esta forma:

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> ListaResumen = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    ListaResumen.put("SubTotal:", subTotal + " " + moneda);
    ListaResumen.put("SubTotal con Descuento:", subTotalDesc + " " + moneda);
    ListaResumen.put("Descuento:", descuento + " " + moneda);
    ListaResumen.put("Envio:", envio + " " + moneda);
    ListaResumen.put("Envio con Descuento:", envioDesc + " " + moneda);
    ListaResumen.put("Impuesto:", impuesto + " " + moneda);
    ListaResumen.put("Impuesto de Envio:", impuestoEnvio + " " + moneda);
    ListaResumen.put("Total:",grandTotal + " " + moneda);
```

de esta forma puede obtener la columna de  descripciones (`valor.getKey()`) y la de valores (`valor.getValue()`) :

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> val : ListaResumen.entrySet()) {
      String descripcion = val.getKey();
      String valor =    val.getValue());
      System.out.println("ListaResumen: " + descripcion + valor);
    }
```

obteniendo:

```
ListaResumen: SubTotal:3 USD
ListaResumen: SubTotal con Descuento:105 USD
ListaResumen: Descuento:0 USD
ListaResumen: Envio:0 USD
ListaResumen: Envio con Descuento:5 USD
ListaResumen: Impuesto:0 USD
ListaResumen: Impuesto de Envio:0 USD
ListaResumen: Total:110 USD
```